# Finding the highest COUNT in a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by

Hello I am new in postgresql . Here is my code for grouping the options and counting them . I want a way though to get only the option with the max count . Is there any way ?

```
SELECT s.option, COUNT(*)
FROM "Set" as s, "Lecture" as l, "Process" as p, "donation" as d
WHERE d.code = p.code and l.type = p.type and l.option = s.option
GROUP BY s.option
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply *give the child a name* (for instance `count`), `ORDER BY` that name, and `LIMIT` to 1:

```
SELECT s.option, COUNT(*) AS count -- give the child a name
FROM "Set" as s, "Lecture" as l, "Process" as p, "donation" as d
WHERE d.code = p.code and l.type = p.type and l.option = s.option
GROUP BY s.option
ORDER BY count DESC -- order by that child in descending order
LIMIT 1 -- and limit the output to one row
```

If you want the *highest*, you should add `DESC` to the `ORDER BY`. In case you want the *lowest*; either do not specify or add `ASC`.

Comment: Is there a way making it using HAVING max(count)?

Comment: @AthanasiaPavlidou: not as far as I know since `HAVING` works with aggregates on the original dataset iirc.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query.  Not only by using PROPER, explicit `JOIN` syntax, but also by getting rid of `Set`:

```
SELECT l.option, COUNT(*)
FROM "Lecture" l JOIN
     "Process" p
     ON l.type = p.type JOIN
     "donation" d
     ON d.code = p.code
GROUP BY l.option
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: There is no `with ties` in Postgres

Comment: I'm not sure if there's `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` either, though I could be wrong.... I'd just use `LIMIT 1` instead anyway.

Comment: @RayO'Donnell: there is a FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY in PgSQL.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Fair enough, I've learnt something new. Is there any difference between it and `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @RayO'Donnell: well based on the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT), probably not.